# Flutter Showcase long description text in one line

Tags: flutter, multiline, showcaseview

I am making this showcaseview in my app using [this](https://pub.flutter-io.cn/packages/showcaseview) library. But I have a long text as the description. But the text will just be in one line like this:

[image: Showcase image]

I really want the text to be in multiple lines. A solution would be to do `\n` to make it a new line, but i would have to do that every time i think it is a long line, and it would be a nightmare.

Is there a better way i could do this?

This is my code:

```
Showcase(
            key: _graph,
            title: 'Diagram',
            description:
                'This is a long description. This is a long description. This is a long description. This is a long description. This is a long description. This is a long description. ',
            child: Container(
              height: _size.height * 0.3,
              child: Diagram()
            ),
          ),
```

Answer (score 0):

Show Case View is supposed to provide a short description of your widget not show multi lines and long descriptions.

**For a Text you can try this:**

```
Container(
  width: 100,
  child: Text(
    'This is a long description. This is a long description. This is a long description. This is a long description. This is a long description. This is a long description. ',
    maxLines: 2,
    overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
  ),
),
```

Comment: Yeah. But the problem is that the description for the Showcase, is not a Text widget but a String.

Comment: Yeah I know there's no mention of multi-line description in their documentation. So if you do want to provide a very long description you'll have to do it the hard way

Answer (score 0):

If you want to provide a longer or custom description try using `Showcase.withWidget()` instead of just `Showcase()`. It takes a `container` property where you can build a custom description widget that incorporates things like `RichText()`.